# Storage account connection string for 'AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsServiceBus' is invalid

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I created an Azure Function App using a ServiceBusTrigger (Listens to a subscription on a Topic). That works fine. But now I'm trying to make a QueueTrigger to listen to a simple queue, but I get the following error.

I went about things in the same way. I created a new project in Visual Studio, pointed it to my storage account on Azure. Specified the queue name. The queue exists. I tried creating a new Shared Access Policy. Copied the connection string into local.settings.json.

```
[2022-02-04T18:30:22.917Z] Found C:\Users\me\.NET\EmailUtilityLogger\EmailUtilityLogger\EmailUtilityLogger.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2022-02-04T18:30:24.684Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection string for 'AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsServiceBus' is invalid.
[2022-02-04T18:30:24.703Z] Error indexing method 'Function1'
[2022-02-04T18:30:24.705Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection string for 'AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsServiceBus' is invalid.
[2022-02-04T18:30:24.706Z] Function 'Function1' failed indexing and will be disabled.
[2022-02-04T18:30:24.709Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[2022-02-04T18:30:24.746Z] The 'Function1' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection string for 'AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsServiceBus' is invalid.
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here... This is mostly default code from generating the project. One odd thing in the error message though is the connection name. It's using "AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsServiceBus" while my connection name is "AzureWebJobsServiceBus".

Here is my app.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace EmailUtilityLogger
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("emailutilititylogger", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

And the local.settings.json file.

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=saneteaidemo;AccountKey=1234abcdsecretstuff==;....",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb://pspeaidemo.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=EmailLogger;SharedAccessKey=1234abcdsecretstuff="
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting shows a connection string name (`AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsServiceBus`) that is not matching the one found in your configuration file (`AzureWebJobsServiceBus`). Validate that the `local.settings.json` is copied over with the newer version of the file and that its contents are matching your project file contents.

Comment: I checked that already. But just now I realized I chose the wrong project template. I need to use the ServiceBusTrigger method, not QueueTrigger. Good grief...

Comment: Happens to the best of us 

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. This case happens when you use [QueueTrigger] from

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.4" />
```

version can be differ..

in this case your setting name should be "AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsServiceBus", azure always adds "AzureWebJobs" before your connection name.
Value in this case should be in connection string format

```
 "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName......"
```

2. Use [QueueTrigger] from different package, replacing

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.4" />
```

by

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.1.2" />
```

in this case you can define exactly "AzureWebJobsServiceBus" in your setting, and additionally, you will be able to define

```
"AzureWebJobsServiceBus__queueServiceUri":"https://xxxxxxx.queue.core.windows.net/"
```

This is advantage to use Azure credential without defining a keys

Answer (score 0):

Updating `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage` package solves this issue.